# Android notify() method is not called

Tags: android, multithreading, locking, java-threads

I'm trying to use notify() and wait(). Here is my desired class. 
I have a problem, when I try to call `addNewItem()`. If I call `tryToReadItem()` first and then call `addNewItem()` method, that log will not be printed. Note that my `DemoClass` is the singleton.

```
public class DemoClass {

private static final String TAG = "DemoClass";

private static DemoClass instance;
private Object lock = new Object();
private static Thread executor;
private static Runnable reader;
static MyQueue queue;


private DemoClass() {
    queue = MyQueue.getInstance();
    reader = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            tryToReadRequest();
        }
    };

}

public static DemoClass getInstance() {
   if (null == instance) {
        instance = new RequestExecutor();
        executor = new Thread(reader);
        executor.run();
    }
    return instance;
}

public boolean addNewItem() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notify();  // executor will be run
        Log.i(TAG, "executor run...");
    }
    return true;
}

public void tryToReadItem() {

    try {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (queue.checkTopValue() == null) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "queue is empty");
                    lock.wait();
                } else {
                    //TODO other code...
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the usage of that class:

```
DemoClass executor = DemoClass.getInstance();
boolean bool = executor.addNewItem();
```

Am I missing something?

Edit: I just changed my code. Now `tryToReadRequest()` is executed continuously while queue is not empty. but my problem is that the line `lock.notify();` does not execute.

Comment: It's all in the same thread. There should be other Thread involved.

Comment: I guess if you change notify to notifyAll you have same result, right?

Comment: Its not related to your problem, but for proper singleton you need synchronized block in getInstance() and e.printStackTrace(); doesnt work in android, you have to write Log.e("tag",Log.getStackTraceString(e)) instead

Comment: @DEADMC no, I tried it but had no difference.

Comment: are *executor.tryToReadItem();
boolean bool = executor.addNewItem();* in different threads?

Comment: @DEADMC yes, tryToReadItem() is executed in a different thread.

Comment: I guess if you place *Log.i(TAG, "executor run...");* before lock.notify you will see printed string, right?

Comment: @DEADMC no, still no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with this code

First of all

```
        if (queue.checkTopValue() == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "queue is empty");
            lock.wait();
        }
```

Depends on [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

> Note: Always invoke wait inside a loop that tests for the condition
>   being waited for. Don't assume that the interrupt was for the
>   particular condition you were waiting for, or that the condition is
>   still true.

Your `DemoClass` is `Singleton`. But not *thread safe* `Singleton`

because multiple threads can pass null == instance condition at the **same** time

```
   if (null == instance) {
        instance = new RequestExecutor();
        executor = new Thread(reader);
        executor.run();
    }
```

Right way is additional check in synchronized block and using volatile instance.

so add volatile to instance

```
private static volatile DemoClass instance;
```

and rewrite getInstance() method to something like this

```
public static DemoClass getInstance() {
    DemoClass localInstance = instance;

    if (localInstance == null) {
        synchronized (DemoClass.class) {
            localInstance = instance;
            if (localInstance == null) {
                localInstance = new DemoClass();
                instance = localInstance;
                executor = new Thread(reader);
                executor.run();
            }
        }
    }
    return localInstance;
}
```

note, you can leave only check inside synchronized block, but that will make getInstance method too slow.